# ImageView not receiving Click events

Tags: basic4android

I was modifying a layout in the designer, and changed the parent of an imageview from a panel to the Activity.  The imageview that previously was in the panel will not respond to clicks. A breakpoint placed in the sub is never reached.

I tried both initializing and not initializing the imageview.  Makes no difference.

Any ideas of why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not initialize views added with the designer. Make sure that the event name property matches the sub name.